# quartz.net thread was being aborted

Tags: c#, multithreading, quartz.net

I'm using Quartz.net to create cron scheduled task in my Windows Service.
I got an ThreadAbortedException that I can't figure out why.
It's appening when I'm trying to get the default scheduler. I read that I need to Shutdown my scheduler, which I did, but it does not fix the problem.
My function is called in a thread, but I don't think it really matters.
Here is my code.

```
public ITrigger InitCronJob(Type jobClass, string pattern = null) {
        ITrigger trigger = null;
        try {
            this.factories.GetLoggerFactory()
                .Log($"Started cron job {jobClass.Name} on {DateTime.Now.ToString(LoggerFactory.dateFormat)}",
                    LogSeverity.Info);
            if (!factories.GetFolderFactory().getConfigFile().ContainsKey("cronPattern") && pattern == null) {
                throw new NoDefinedCronPattern("There is no cron pattern defined in the config.");
            }
            if (this.defaultScheduler == null) {
                this.defaultScheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler(); // problem seams to be here.
            }

            IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create(jobClass).Build();
            trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("myJob - " + jobClass.Name + " - " + Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "myJob")
                .WithCronSchedule(pattern ?? factories.GetFolderFactory().getConfigFile()["cronPattern"])
                .StartAt(DateTime.UtcNow)
                .WithPriority(1)
                .Build();
            this.defaultScheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
            this.defaultScheduler.Start();
        }
        finally {
            defaultScheduler?.Shutdown(true);
        }
        
        return trigger;
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to explicitly initialize your factory before the call?

Comment: @VMAtm that's a good idea. I will try it out.

Comment: How often do you call this method? It calls every time `this.defaultScheduler.Start();`, i guess that's the problem.

Comment: Maybe, it,s about once or twice when the application starts.

Comment: I have seen the `ThreadAbortedException` occur when thread that scheduler is to set to run on is aborted unexpectedly.  For example if a windows service is stopped and `defaultScheduler?.Shutdown(true);` is not part of the stop service logic - essentially an ungraceful shutdown of the scheduler.

Comment: @Nicolas, did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Comment: @rimkojr turns out the exception was caused by another exception. If you can get the complete stack trace, you should be able to find out another exception. The `threadAbortedException` was just the highest in the trace, thus the one I thought I had. Hope it helps !